# Liquibase with Unsupported Database

Tags: liquibase

I am trying liquibase with unsupported database ExaSol.

It is failing due to following exception

```
liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Feature not supported: user-defined type (DATETIME) [line 1, column 110] (Session: 1613843703712878739) [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE SCH.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED datetime, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))]
```

It seems it is failing because of DATETIME datatype. I tried with --currentDateTimeFunction as well. Its not working.

Can someone guide me on how to handle this situation

Comment: I guess you would have to create an [extension](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/spaces/CONTRIB/overview). There are examples on that page for other databases that are no supported by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this solution: 
Replace the data type from datetime to TIMESTAMP and after changing the code this way, try:

```
CREATE or replace TABLE abc.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED timestamp, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```